# Emacs buffer undo limit

Tags: matlab, emacs

I get this warning in my `matlab-shell` buffer when I print alot to stdout:

```
Warning (undo): Buffer `*MATLAB*' undo info was 12268000 bytes long.
The undo info was discarded because it exceeded `undo-outer-limit'.

This is normal if you executed a command that made a huge change
to the buffer.  In that case, to prevent similar problems in the
future, set `undo-outer-limit' to a value that is large enough to
cover the maximum size of normal changes you expect a single
command to make, but not so large that it might exceed the
maximum memory allotted to Emacs.
```

My emacs looks like this:
[image]

I really don't need any undo in the `matlab-shell` which is the right buffer. Is there a way to disable this warning? Note that the left buffer is a `MATLAB` script which means that the major mode is MATLAB, and certainly undo should not be disabled there.

Comment: Well which mode is the `*MATLAB*` buffer in? I can see that the lighter text is "M-Shell". I'm going to guess it's a `matlab-shell-mode`, but if you use `C-h m` then you can tell us.

Comment: @phils, your guess is right. It is matlab-shell mode. Do the modes in left and right are different?

Comment: Are they different? Well one is a mode to assist with editing source code for a particular language, and one is a mode for interacting with an external running process. Despite both being related to MATLAB, the two activities have very little in common.

Comment: @phils, Thanks. I don't understand what star_MATLAB_star means then on the right buffer. Does it have anything to do with MATLAB mode.

Comment: No, that's the buffer name, just like "frequency_response.m" is the name of the buffer in the left window. File-visiting buffers are named after the file they are visiting (but 'uniquified' if you open multiple files with the same filename). Non-file buffers like \*MATLAB\* typically have names beginning and ending with an asterisk (I'm not actually sure if this is a documented convention, but it's obviously intended to prevent naming conflicts with actual files).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous, but assuming you're saying that you have no need to *undo* things in this buffer, then you can disable the undo system on a per-buffer basis:

```
buffer-disable-undo is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `simple.el'.

(buffer-disable-undo &optional BUFFER)

Make BUFFER stop keeping undo information.
No argument or nil as argument means do this for the current buffer.
```

So you can call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `buffer-disable-undo` <kbd>RET</kbd> interactively, or if you're sure about it, you could add this to a hook function for the mode in question.

**Edit:**

So based on the extra information in the question comments, I would suggest this:

```el
(add-hook 'matlab-shell-mode-hook 'buffer-disable-undo)
```

Comment: I updated the question. `buffer-disable-undo` answers the question partially.

Answer (score 13):

As that warning message says (or used to say?):

> You can disable the popping up of this buffer by adding the entry
>   `(undo discard-info)` to the user option `warning-suppress-types`,
>   which is defined in the `warnings` library.

That is:

```
(add-to-list 'warning-suppress-types '(undo discard-info))
```

(That will of course just disable the warning, not the undo data collection itself.)